# how to get the already copied files' list when using cp command in the bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I use the cp command in the bash shell with the --update options, which copy only when the source file is newer than the destination file.

I don't know how to get the already copied files list.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cp -v`

From the man page

> -v, --verbose
>
> ```
>           explain what is being done
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i want.